# Cant find kivy logs when running with Kivy Launcher

Tags: android, python, kivy, crash-reports

When running my kivy app on Android Kivy Launcher it crashes instantly. I've looked everywhere for the logs, but couldn't find them. No .kivy folder is created, apps that view android logcat require root access and I couldn't get working adb logcat. Can someone explain to me how to use adb logcat to catch the error, or state another solution to my problem?

PS: The app uses kivy 1.9.1 and py 3.4.4, runs fine on windows and my cellphone is a Xperia Z5 running Android Marshmallow 6.0.1

Comment: Where did you get the launcher from? Some logs (kivy only) should be in `sdcard/kivy/<project>/.kivy/logs`

Comment: Kivy Launcher on Play store

Comment: Did the app run correctly (have you seen widgets)?

Comment: No, the error I found on the logs is that the launcher uses python 2.7, while my app is in 3.4. Some parts, such as `import tkinter` and `super(self, **kwargs).__init__()` crash my program. Can I get it to work with python3 or do I have to adapt all my code to be compatible with python2?

Comment: Launcher from google play is Python 2 only. `tkinter` probably won't work on android and basically you can't cross Kivy and other UI framework, it just won't do. And your [`super()`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/compatibility-between-python-3-and-python-2/9712/compatible-subclassing-with-super) is just bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out how to use adb logcat. Install android studio 2.2. Connect your device to the PC via USB and enable debugging mode in the developer options. cd in command prompt to C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools, and run adb devices. If the serial number of your android device appears, you're good to go. Then run adb logcat while executing the kivy app in your phone, and you'll get the realtime logs.